# multiprocessing Linux and Windows - passing variables

Tags: python, linux, windows, scipy, multiprocessing

I wrote a program that does use multiprocessing module. The program was initially written for Linux but I want to allow also Windows users to use it. The main issue is when passing variables (or rather interpolation functions) to subroutines - on Linux I don't have to make explict use of the interpolation function 'interpolator' and my call for subrotines looks like like:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print 'Executing main loop...'
result2 = []
for i in range(0,NN):
    pool.apply_async(SliceCalculate, (i), callback=result2.append)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

and all seem to work fine !  The 'SliceCalculate' function uses inside:

```
interpolator=interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(xyzpoints,weights,rescale=True)
```

and finds 'interpolator' automaticaly. On Windows the call needs to look like:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print 'Executing main loop...'
result2 = []
for i in range(0,NN):
    pool.apply_async(SliceCalculate, (i,interpolator), callback=result2.append)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

and also works. Except one thing - performance drops to something like 40% (same machine used).I compared both version on Linux - on Windows the program meant for Windows has same poor performance while if I try to run the Linux version (no passing 'interpolator') I don't get any results. Any ideas what is wrong ?
I can't share the whole program - its simply too long.

PS. I did some more tests and it seems like when the 'interpolator' is big (e.g. the interpolation values in 3D go to 100x100x100 what I need) then the performance is as described above but when I limit it to e.g. 40x40x40 interpolation points (source points) then the performance of both solutions is same and starts to vary as the 'interpolator' size increases (NearestNDInterpolator us used). Could it be the OS 'issue' and actually I can't do much more ?

Comment: This seems to be related to `scipy` rather than `multiprocessing` itself. Are you using the same version in both systems?

Comment: Just installed on both system, so Linux has 0.17.0 and Windows has 1.1.0. Python is 2.7.12 and 2.7.15 respectively. The version shouldn't have such impact on performance I guess. In fact, the 'windows version' where I pass the 'interpolator' to SliceCalculate call has not much better performance than when it was serial (did such test also - in this case there is also no need to pass the 'interpolator' to function call it seems to be treated globally for both Windows and Linux